# How to call async task by using .ContinueWith

Tags: c#, bitmap, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm building one Bitmap out of several Bitmaps. What I doing is calling multiple methods that return a Task.

The problem I'm running into is the deadlock, because I'm attempting to retrieve the value from the async methods that are in the .ContinueWith() by .Result, and this doesn't work because it turns a async method int a sync method, and this leads me to a deadlock.

My question is how do I call the async methods inside the .ContinueWith, and or what is the proper way to implement this type of methods?

I need to remove the .Result and call the async method Task correctly. What is the correct way?

**Here is my code.**

```
 public async static Task<Bitmap> RollUpDrawingsImage(IElevation elevation)
{
    int height = 0, width = 800;
    Bitmap completeDrawings = null;

    using (Bitmap elevationDoor = await ShopDrawing.Merger.MergeElevationAndDoor(elevation, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone))
    {
        using (Bitmap partsList = await MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialList(elevation).ContinueWith(async (ml) => await ml.Result.GetDrawing()).Result)
        {
            using (Bitmap optimized = await Optimization.Manager.GetOptimizedParts(elevation).ContinueWith(async (op) => await op.Result.GetDrawing()).Result)
            {
                using (Bitmap cutSheet = await CutSheet.Manager.GetCutSheet(elevation).ContinueWith(async (cs) => await cs.Result.GetDrawing()).Result)
                {
                    height = (elevationDoor.Height + optimized.Height + cutSheet.Height + partsList.Height);
                    completeDrawings = new Bitmap(width, height + 40);

                    using (var dc = Graphics.FromImage(completeDrawings))
                    {
                        dc.DrawImageUnscaled(elevationDoor, 0, 0);

                        dc.DrawImageUnscaled(partsList, 0, elevationDoor.Height + 10);

                        dc.DrawImageUnscaled(optimized, 0, (elevationDoor.Height + partsList.Height) + 20);

                        dc.DrawImageUnscaled(cutSheet, 0, (elevationDoor.Height + partsList.Height + optimized.Height) + 30);
                    };

                    return completeDrawings;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes you think you need `ContinueWith`?

The appropriate replacement for `Result` is `await`. As a side note, you should end `async` methods with "Async":

```
public async static Task<Bitmap> RollUpDrawingsImage(IElevation elevation)
{
  int height = 0, width = 800;
  Bitmap completeDrawings = null;

  using (Bitmap elevationDoor = await ShopDrawing.Merger.MergeElevationAndDoorAsync(elevation, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone))
  using (Bitmap partsList = await (await MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialListAsync(elevation)).GetDrawingAsync())
  using (Bitmap optimized = await (await Optimization.Manager.GetOptimizedPartsAsync(elevation)).GetDrawingAsync())
  using (Bitmap cutSheet = await (await CutSheet.Manager.GetCutSheetAsync(elevation)).GetDrawingAsync())
  {
    height = (elevationDoor.Height + optimized.Height + cutSheet.Height + partsList.Height);
    completeDrawings = new Bitmap(width, height + 40);

    using (var dc = Graphics.FromImage(completeDrawings))
    {
      dc.DrawImageUnscaled(elevationDoor, 0, 0);
      dc.DrawImageUnscaled(partsList, 0, elevationDoor.Height + 10);
      dc.DrawImageUnscaled(optimized, 0, (elevationDoor.Height + partsList.Height) + 20);
      dc.DrawImageUnscaled(cutSheet, 0, (elevationDoor.Height + partsList.Height + optimized.Height) + 30);
    }

    return completeDrawings;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've would like to expand on the ending my async methods with async. What if I'm returning a Task<T>? Would that method need to and with async?

Comment: Yes, it should end with `Async`.

Comment: Thank you again Stephen! They should call you Async man of the year!